# Close vim NERDtree on close of file

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am trying out Vim, installed some plugins, amongst which NERDTree, followed some guides and set up a `.vimrc` (half of whose content I don't understand — yet).

What annoys me, is that if I `:wq`, vim remains active, it only closes the documents' split-screen. I end up with a fullscreen NERDTree. I would like NERDTree to close too, on closing the last tab or buffers.

Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically quit vim if NERDTree is last and only buffer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066590/automatically-quit-vim-if-nerdtree-is-last-and-only-buffer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `:wqa` command will write all changed buffers and exit Vim. This will close down NerdTree, too.

Answer (score 21):

Put this in your vimrc:

```
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") 
      \ && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
```

Note: `\` is to allow multiple line commands

Comment: This solution works better if you don't want to type wqa

Comment: This does not work for me. Very strange. Any tip on how to find out that. I do not get any errors so I do not if it is run at all.

Comment: I find that, it normally work if default open with tree view. If I default open without tree view, and type `:NERDTreeCWD` or `:NERDTreeToggle`, then  need `:q` twice.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, using `:q` just close current split so for closing all splits go back to the terminal we should use `:qa`, this command closes all splits even NERDTree.

There is a shortcut for `:wq` and it is `:x`, the `:x` write the changes and close the current split, if you wanna save all changes and close all splits and go back to the terminal you can use below command too:

```
:xa
```

That is equivalent to:

```
:wqa
```