# Close vim if no "unhidden" buffers open

Tags: vim

Is there any script that closes vim if there are only utility buffers open? I have seen some scrips for NERDTree ([Close vim NERDtree on close of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581697/close-vim-nerdtree-on-close-of-file)), but none that is more general.

An example, because I am unsure if it is clear what I mean.

1. Tagbar, Magit and a file are open
2. I close the file
3. only utility buffers are open (both buffers are hidden from :ls) -> vim closes

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: In the absence of a common definition of "utility buffer"/"utility window", you are left with dumb plugin-specific pattern matching, as in the linked thread, and the obligation to update your solution whenever you add a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to do what you want:

```
augroup auto_close_win
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * call s:quit_current_win()
augroup END

" Quit Nvim if we have only one window, and its filetype match our pattern.
function! s:quit_current_win() abort
  let quit_filetypes = ['qf', 'vista']
  let buftype = getbufvar(bufnr(), '&filetype')
  if winnr('$') == 1 && index(quit_filetypes, buftype) != -1
    quit
  endif
endfunction
```

We use autocmd `BufEnter` to check if we have only one window left and the filetype of the current buffer is in the blacklist.

Update the list `quit_filetypes` to include the filetypes you have in mind.