# Remap vim :x to close buffer, only exiting if it is the last buffer

Tags: vim

I would like to change the <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> command in Vim so that it closes a buffer unless it is the last buffer then it should behave as it does now (i.e close vim).

I've read some stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513380/vim-change-x-function-to-delete-buffer-instead-of-save-quit) but it doesn't go all the way. I also use NERDTree and would like that to be ignored when considering if it's the last buffer.

I have a partially working solution based on the link I referred to but this makes it impossible to exit vim using a vim command (becase the exit command has been remapped).

I have

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> x getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'x' ? 'w<bar>bd' : 'x'
cnoreabbrev <expr> wq getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'wq' ? 'w<bar>bd' : 'wq'
cnoreabbrev <expr> q getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'q' ? 'bd' : 'q'
```

So <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> (or <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>) will save and close the current buffer and :q will just close it.

What I would like to add is... If that buffer is also the last buffer (ignoring NERDTree) then it will also exit vim.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Have you tried `:q` instead of `:x`? It does pretty much what you want, but doesn't save on exit (which you can force using `:wq`).

Comment: :q does not close the buffer, it just hides it.

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't fully read the question.

Comment: Fyi, you can simply use `:bd` to close the current buffer.

Comment: I know. But after 2 decades of typing :x, old habits die hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Automatically quit vim if NERDTree is last and only buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066590/automatically-quit-vim-if-nerdtree-is-last-and-only-buffer) works:

```
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif
```