# Vim-airline close buffer/quit vim

Tags: vim, vim-airline

With vim and vim-airline, I've got a situation where I want to be able to close a buffer if it exist, and if not close vim.

So I've first remmapped `:x` to `;x` for speed reasons.

```
nnoremap : ;
```

Then I mapped `;x` to close the buffers opened with vim-airline

```
nnoremap :x :bp <BAR> bd #<CR>
```

Now the issue is when I finally close all the buffers, I can't use `;x` to quit vim.

Is there any way to check if a buffer exist in vim-airline and close it? 
Saw [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886576/remap-vim-x-to-close-buffer-only-exiting-if-it-is-the-last-buffer) but its more for NERDTree.

Comment: [`nnoremap` is non-recursive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3776117/78845) and won't call your other mappings.

Comment: Alright, so would that mean my `nnoremap : ;` would need to be changed or the buffer close command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: `nnoremap : ;` will change the `:` key to invoke the original value of the `;` command, i.e. skip to the next character matched by `f`, `F`, `t` or `T`. If you want to use `;x`, you need to remap the reverse: `nnoremap ; :`.

`nnoremap :x ...` will then use the original value of `:` for `:x`, so everything should work fine. Alternately, and less safely, you could do `nmap ;x ...` to invoke the redefined value of `:` (and potentially a redefined value of `x` as well, if you specified `map! x`, `cmap x`, `lmap x`, or their non-recursive variants).

Also, `:bd` will not close the Vim, only the buffer and a window. If you're on your last buffer, you get dumped into a new unnamed buffer (like with `:enew`). To close buffer or Vim, use `:q`, that's what it's for.

(Also, I don't understand what you meant by "buffer exist in vim-airline". Airline is a status bar plugin. Buffers either exist or not. The two have nothing to do with each other, at least not in a way that is obvious to me.)