# Automatically quit vim if netrw is last and only buffer

Tags: vim

This is simillar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066590/automatically-quit-vim-if-nerdtree-is-last-and-only-buffer) , but I'm not using NERDTree , instead netrw for same purpose. I have tried tweaking the script in my .vimrc a little bit , but I have no idea what do netrw buffers are named as.

With NERDTree this went well , but having tough luck with netrw.

```
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `.vimrc` file

```
aug netrw_close
  au!
  au WinEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && getbufvar(winbufnr(winnr()), "&filetype") == "netrw"|q|endif
aug END
```

#### Warnings

I did not test the code above.

Netrw can easily be the only open window. This would mean your Vim instance would close unexpectedly. It would be better to learn how to use `:qa` if you want to close all the windows.

Comment: Yes , :qa is proper way to do this. I went a bit overboard with this one :p