# quit code checker when when quitting vim

Tags: vim, python-mode, flake8

I'm using vim with python-mode plugin. When I quit vim with `wq` or `q`, the code check on the bottom doesn't quit. Just wondering if there is a config for quitting code check when vim quit? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't use that plugin but looks like it keeps the location list window open while you code? You can use `:wqa` or `:qa` to close all windows.

Comment: I also don't use that plugin but it sounds something like this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066590/automatically-quit-vim-if-nerdtree-is-last-and-only-buffer, so it might be usefull to you!

Comment: @iovis, thanks! :wqa or :qa works fine with me

Comment: @dNitro, I changed a little bit of the vimscript from here: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/21
and it works on my vim. Thanks!

Comment: @yfeng maybe you could post what you modified as an answer and accept it? glad you found a solution.